# Why does this quicksort appear to be faster than std::sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, quicksort

Why does it appear that this quicksort algorithm is faster than std::sort? I've checked to make sure it's actually sorting the array. I've also replaced both sorting calls with hollow for loops of the same number of iterations to test the timing benchmark and everything checked out there.

I'm also wondering what adjustments I can make to the quicksort to allow it to recurse more times. Maybe some sort of variable memory management?

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <vector>       
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
void quickSort(int*, int);
void fillRandom(int*, int,int b2);
int main() {
    //setup arrays
    int size = 100000;
    auto myints = new int[size];
    auto myints2 = new int[size];
    fillRandom(myints, size,10000);
    std::copy(myints, myints + size, myints2);

    //measurement 1
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    quickSort(myints, size);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << endl << "Execution 1 took: "<< duration << endl;

    //measurement 2
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(myints2,myints2+size);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << endl << "Execution 2 took: " << duration << endl;


    cout << "finished!";
    return 1;
}
void fillRandom(int* p, int size,int upTo) {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        p[i] = rand() % upTo + 1;
    }
}
void quickSortSwap(int *p1, int*p2) {
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;

}
void quickSort(int* original, int len) {
    int split = *original;
    int greaterIndex = len - 1;
    int lesserIndex = 1;
    int* currentP;
    //rearrange stuff so smaller is left, bigger is right
    for (int i = 1;i < len;i++) {
        currentP = original + lesserIndex;
        //cout << *currentP << " compared to " << split << endl;
        if (*currentP <= split) {
            lesserIndex++;
        }
        else {
            //cout << "greater: " << *currentP <<endl;
            quickSortSwap(currentP, original + greaterIndex);
            greaterIndex--;
        }
    }

    //uhh, now we switch pivot element with the right most left side element. Adjust our left side length measurement accordingly.
    lesserIndex--;
    quickSortSwap(original, original + lesserIndex);
    greaterIndex++;
    //this point
    if (lesserIndex > 1) {
        quickSort(original, lesserIndex);
    }
    int greater_range = len - greaterIndex;
    if (greater_range > 1) {
        quickSort(original + greaterIndex, greater_range);
    }
}
```

https://rextester.com/AOPBP48224

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @alter of course not, who asks an optimization question on SO after doing that?

Comment: Note that many elements will be equal in the array. This might bias the comparison a little bit. Besides, I guess you check that you quicksort provides correct results;

Comment: You only get the time of a single run with cold cache. Average over multiple iterations to get reliable results. And don't forget to turn optimizations to maximum.

Comment: Yours is reliably slower (~20-50%) for me, but with a much higher variance than the standard library. (So high that it was actually faster once in a dozen runs. Perhaps you got lucky?)

Comment: I tested you programme. I found that often (not always), `std::sort` is slightly faster. I compiled with `gcc -O3`.

Comment: See my test [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iSJy0olcYzKYKHJO). With optimizations enabled, `std::sort` is consistently significantly faster.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/frbxMz https://rextester.com/AOPBP48224

Comment: I wish there was a FAQ or SO guideline that explains the proper requirements when posting a question on performance.   Too many questions get either "closed" by the original poster when all they need is to turn optimizations on, and/or "oops, I didn't know that" when the same tests are rerun with optimizations turned on.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie create respective topic on [meta].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio's std::sort has some overhead and some optimizations that your program does not. Your program is based on Lomuto partition scheme, while std::sort is a single pivot, 3 partition Hoare like quicksort + insertion sort for small partitions. The 3 partitions are elements < pivot, elements == pivot, elements > pivot. If there are no duplicate values, the 3 partition sort is just some overhead. If there are duplicate values, then as the number of duplicate values increases, Lomuto gets worse, and Hoare or std::sort get better. Try using fillRandom(myints, size,10); and you should see a large performance hit with Lomuto method, and an increase in performance with std::sort().

Visual Studio's std::sort uses median of nine if >= 40 elements, median of 3 for 33 to 39 elements, which reduces the probability of worst case scenarios, and switches to insertion sort for <= 32 elements (this speeds it up). To reduce stack overhead, it uses recursion for the smaller partition, and loops back to handle the larger partition. It has a check to avoid worst case time complexity O(n^2), switching to heap sort if the depth of partitioning ("recursions") becomes excessive. It uses iterators instead of plain pointers, but in release mode, my impression is the iterators are unchecked, and effectively pointers. It also uses a function pointer for less than compare, defaulting to std::less, which I don't know if it get optimized away.

Comment: I ran the code (without optimization) for  fillRandom(myints, size,10), std::sort was almost 10 times faster

Comment: @JimCastro  _"...without optimization..."_  wasting your time.  The non-optimized version is written for ease of debugging with lots of conditional compilation for bounds checking, iterator validity etc.

Comment: Beautifully detailed answer the tacitly explains why not to roll-your-own. Technically it's not Visual Studio but MSVC

Comment: @AluanHaddad - rolling your own would be faster based on knowledge of what is being sorted. std::sort is setup to be very generic, allowing the sorting of any container of objects with random access iterators, with the option of a user specified compare function. For example, if just sorting integers, it's not difficult to write faster code.  On my system, sorting 16 million pseudo random 64 bit unsigned integers takes 1.25 seconds with my own introsort program, 1.50 seconds with std::sort, not much of a penalty for such a generic implementation.